# AngularJs Directive in MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to following directive [numericOnly] in a textbox which is written as in Razor?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.salary, new { data_ng_model = "salary" })

app.directive('numericOnly', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (inputValue) {
                var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function (s) { return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' '); }).join('');

                if (digits.length > 6) {
                    digits = digits.substring(0, 5);
                }

                ngModel.$viewValue = digits;
                ngModel.$render();
                return digits;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Please suggest anyone.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As directive should be written as in small case with `-` separated, Camel case is replaced by small letter and `-`(hyphen) like `numericOnly` become `numeric-only`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.salary, new { data_ng_model = "salary", type = "text", numeric_only = ""})
```

**Result**

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="salary" numeric-only="" />
```

Comment: pankajparkar Excellent! Thank you